# What does this odd-looking contraption on the back of an electrical power utility pickup truck do?

Tags: power-grid

Spotted on a Con Ed truck driving around Brooklyn, NY streets late at night.

Some kind of EM field sensor maybe?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you tap on it?  Is the rounded thing plastic or metal?

Comment: Ground penetrating radar or something of that ilk?  Does it swing downward? Looks expensive and made in small quantity.

Comment: Ground penetrating radars are bulkier and closer to the ground. Thermal imagers would have a lens. Maybe a high-accuracy GPS? Could also be a magnetic sensor. Intriguing, hope we get an answer.

Comment: Is there a lens opening underneath? Could it be an automated manhole cover inspection system? https://www.ntt-review.jp/archive/ntttechnical.php?contents=ntr201808fa3_s.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking at a Stray Voltage Detection system, model SVD-2000. It detects electric fields produced by metallic objects that have accidentally become electrified due to an insulation fault -- a lamp post, for example. There was a fatality in 2004 and a $10 million settlement. Here's a [news article](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/02/17/nyregion/17shock.html), and information from [a supplier](https://www.osmose.com/power-survey-technology).

Good question! I learned something!

Comment: Good catch. We had some incidents locally about 10-15 years ago with multiple canine fatalities. I don't recall any human victims.

Comment: Wow ! How the heck did you find that?!

Comment: @bigjosh Google should get much of the credit, but you have to guess the right keywords -- "Con Ed stray voltage sensor" is one winner.